# no sound in fedora 18

Tags: virtualbox, fedora

I installed Fedora 18 Xfce Spin as a guest operating system on VirtualBox.It has no sound.

The operating system settings are:

- Host Driver:Windows DirectSound
- Controller:ICH AC97

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my question's answer [Here](http://fedoraunity.org/Members/fenris02/pulseaudio-fixes-and-workarounds).
 Problem is not about virtualbox audio settings on guest operating system.The settings should be like I made.xfce-mixer was not installed.After I had installed the problem gone.

Perhaps that post helps another searcher.